# Assign values to Julia Matrix based on Condition

Tags: julia

I have a matrix of zeros `A` which has dimension `(m x n)`. I have another matrix of some integer values `b`. `b` has length `n`. I want to have `A` be set to the identity wherever `b` has values greater than 5. So basically, for every row of `A` where `b` has value greater than 5, set it to the identity.

I tried to do this, but it's not working. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this in Julia?

```
using LinearAlgebra
usable_values = filter((x) -> x > 5, b)
# A[:, usable_values] = I
A[:, b .> 5] = I
```

Comment: `A[:, b .> 5] .= I`? Note the dot before equal sign.

Comment: and for the first approach, use `findall` instead of `filter`, which returns the indexes of those meet the condition.

Comment: @张实唯 It gives me an error: `MethodError: no method matching length(::UniformScaling{Bool})`

Comment: sorry for being too lazy to provide a full working example, but luckily there is tholy :) Just see his great long answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand what you mean by "set to the identity": the identity matrix must be square, and hence a row or column of a matrix can't be equal to the identity matrix. I'll operate under the assumption that you want the entries to have value 1. In that case,

```
A[:, findall(b .> 5)] .= 1
```

is a simple one-liner. Let's discuss the elements here:

- As proposed above, `filter` will select out the elements of `b` bigger than 5. But you want the indices of those elements, for which `findall` is the appropriate function.
- Note the use of broadcasted assignment, `.=`. This means to assign the RHS to each element of the left side. That way you don't need to create a matrix on the RHS.

The loop approach is fine too, but for reasons of performance I'd put that in a function. See the [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/).

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is *for every row of A where b has value greater than 5, set it to the identity* this might be helpful to you, while you wait that for some of the gurus here can write the same in one line of code :)

```
n = 2
m = 5
A = zeros(m, n)
b = rand(1:10, m)

println(b)

for (cnt, value) in enumerate(b)
    if value > 5
        A[cnt, :] = ones(1, n)
    end
end
A
```

The result I get is:

```
b = [4, 2, 6, 8, 1]

5×2 Array{Float64,2}:
0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0
1.0  1.0
0.0  0.0
```

I am fairly new to the language, this is the best I can do to help, for now.

Comment: Yeah this technically would work, but I was hoping for something more Julia like. I gave you an upvote though.

Comment: I know what you mean! :)